# Is there a place for more frivolous questions related to programming / computers?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, quality

I've come to realize in my short time at stack overflow that the users are very strict about the type and quality of questions on the site.

Is there an associated site where more frivolous questions could be asked? For example, I asked a question on career choices in the IT industry, which was closed by several users. What would be the right place for such a question, if at all there is one. At first glance, SUPER USER doesn't seem to be the answer.

Comment: For the very frivolous ones: http://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index?sid=396545660 ?

Comment: *"the users are very strict about the type and quality of questions on the site"* ::grumble:: That depends on the user. There are more than a few that think that SO and SF *are* places for frivolous questions. ::grumble::

Comment: @dmckee: nothing wrong with frivolity, so long as it's on-topic.  see for example ["How do I teach my command line manners?"](http://superuser.com/questions/148053/how-do-i-teach-my-command-line-manners): certainly frivolous, but clearly (once you read the question) on-topic.  i'm not sure whether IT career questions are frivolous, but they're definitely *not* on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could propose such a site at area51.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There already is one - [Not Programming Related](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related)